# What does that line mean in ObjectScript?

Tags: intersystems-cache, objectscript

This is a line in class `MonCache.DB` of [this project](https://github.com/intersystems-ru/MonCache):

```
s fieldsNames = ##class(MonCache.Types.Object) modificationOperator.getNames()
```

It is the first time I see that... Is that a cast, by any chance?

Comment: http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20152/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GOBJ_specialcos#GOBJ_specialcos_lblbclass

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes; however in this syntax there are no spaces between ##class(...) and the argument

Comment: [*"Note that whitespace can be inserted or omitted almost anywhere in Caché ObjectScript"*](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20102/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCOS_intro)

Comment: @jonrsharpe you can certainly understand that nobody recalls each and everything they have ever read; and the first link you point to does not explicitly mention that spaces are allowed there

Comment: I don't expect you to recall *anything*, let alone *everything*; why bother given that you can look it up as needed? However I would expect you to research, particularly given your rep. I've never even used ObjectScript and still found both of those links with a few seconds on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [method casting](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20152/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GOBJ_methods#GOBJ_methods_castmethod) and whitespace does not matter in this particular context.